# Create a count table with unequal number to variables

Tags: r

I have the following dataset `zx`:

```
#zx

      A      B    C       D
1    COW    COW  BIRD   COW
2    COW   BIRD  COW    COW
3 FLOWER    DND  BIRD    DND
4    COW    COW  BIRD  FLOWER
5 FLOWER FLOWER  DND    COW
6 FLOWER    COW  COW    BIRD
```

I want to create a count table which should look like this:

```
        A   B   C   D
COW     3   3   2   3
BIRD    0   1   3   1
FLOWER  3   1   0   1
DND     0   1   1   1
```

I have tried using following code but it shows an error as there is no `DND` and `BIRD` in first column, i.e. there is an unequal number of variables among columns:

```
countsd <-  data.frame(apply(zx, 2, count))
```

Comment: `library(tidyr) ; zx %>% gather() %>% table() %>% t()`

Comment: `t(table(data.frame(as.table(t(zx)))[-2]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` column wise.

Basically, creating every element into a `factor` with all the unique values present in the dataframe as `levels` and then calculating the frequency of that level in the column.

```
apply(zx, 2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique(unlist(zx)))))

#       A B C D
#COW    3 3 2 3
#FLOWER 3 1 0 1
#BIRD   0 1 3 1
#DND    0 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.
Basically you are vectorizing your data frame here row wise and then creating the table.

```
> table(as.vector(t(zx)),rep(names(zx),nrow(zx)))
```

You will get the following output

```
        A B C D
 BIRD   0 1 3 1
 COW    3 3 2 3
 DND    0 1 1 1
 FLOWER 3 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To call `table`, melt your data to long form so each letter is paired with its word. `tidyr::gather` is one function that does this:

```
library(tidyr)

zx %>% gather() %>% head()

##   key  value
## 1   A    COW
## 2   A    COW
## 3   A FLOWER
## 4   A    COW
## 5   A FLOWER
## 6   A FLOWER
```

Then call `table`. You can specify order, although its default is to make a table with each variable, which is what you want. The order is backwards, though, so `t`ranspose to rearrange:

```
zx %>% gather() %>% table() %>% t()

##         key
## value    A B C D
##   BIRD   0 1 3 1
##   COW    3 3 2 3
##   DND    0 1 1 1
##   FLOWER 3 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(zx))
#       A B C D
#BIRD   0 1 3 1
#COW    3 3 2 3
#DND    0 1 1 1
#FLOWER 3 1 0 1
```